# Guacamole 1.3.0. Проблема с кодировкой в clipboard между Linux и Windows

Tags: apache

При копировании текста в буфер обмена из Linux машины в хостовую, кириллица заменяется на: **\u0422\u0415**
в user-mapping к этому соединению добавлял параметр "clipboard-encoding", перебрал все варианты кодировок из официальной инструкции,подходящей не нашел. Cервер guacamole стоит на убунту 18.04

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]